# Android open another application from EditText

Tags: android

Can we open other app through this code by executing command given through the Edittext view. If yes then how it can be done?

```
package com.example.honey.shell;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView op;
 EditText ip;
 Button exec;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  op = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  exec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 }

 public void execute(View view) {
  String input = ip.getText().toString();
  StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
  Process p;
  try {
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(input);
   p.waitFor();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   String line = "";
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {}
  op.setText(output.toString());
 }
```

}

Actually i wish to open some other application from my app by executing the command but it's not working,as I tried commands such as cd but it didn't work only the ls command is working in it...

Comment: where do you invoke the method execute? and that method is not for opening other application either

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you getting any erros? Please take a look at here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hey liya, the execute method is invoked by clicking the button, which i have placed in my layout file.

Answer (score 0):

to open an application from another app , you can use Intents

```
Intent launchNewApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.name");//specify the package name of other application which you intended to launch
if (launchNewApp != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Comment: dude this will be for a particular application but i want to open the app by executing the command.